# How to solve too many redirects problem - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently I made a small change in my API domain path, I don't want to update my app and I want to solve the URL issue using a `.htaccess` file.

My current API domain is : `https://api.example.com`

I need to redirect to `https://api.example.com/en/`

I have API for

- English - `https://api.example.com/en`
- Arabic - `https://api.example.com/ar`

But my current Englsh API is `https://api.example.com` only, and I need to add `/en/` to it.

If it is `/ar/` already then no need to do anything.

I want to redirect to `https://api.example.com/en/` if the access domain is only `https://api.example.com`.

Because before I served the English version of my API directly from the domain but now I've separated that to `en` - for English and `ar` for Arabic.

My code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://api.example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Error :

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

In the address bar I can see

`http://api.example.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/`

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: “is only `https://api.example.com`“ - what about `https://api.example.com/foo`?

Comment: it should  redirect to https://api.example.com/en/foo  & if it is https://api.example.com/ar/foo  then no need to change anything.

Comment: This should help: [Redirect URL without lang directory to default language](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/redirect-url-without-lang-directory-to-default-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the requested URL-path does not already start with `/en/` or `/ar/`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|ar)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://api.example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^(en|ar)/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

*Aside:* Since this is an "API", are requests expecting to have to follow redirects?

Comment: yes. currently our app is running in user devices.

Comment: i'm still getting same problem "Too many redirects"

Comment: @Jhonywalker20 Have you cleared your browser cache? The very same "redirect-loop"? Where exactly are you putting this rule? A redirect like this needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file. Where is your `.htaccess` file located? We may need to see you complete `.htaccess` file. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: its worked after clearing cache !, thanks so much

Comment: its works, but giving error in my flutter app why ?

Comment: I think it's expecting to have to follow redirects. its working in POSTMAN app as expected.
How i can fix ?